# Repeat each line multiple times

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, perl

Would like to have each line in a file repeated a fixed number of times.

e.g. have each line repeated four times:

```
a
b
c
```

becomes:

```
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
c
c
c
c
```

I've done some searching, and there are a lot of questions and answers along the lines of doing the reverse, e.g. merging duplicate lines into single lines, and maybe a few about doubling lines by printing them again.

It would be easy to do this in C, but I wish I knew more about the native commands so I wouldn't have to resort to these kinds of one-off throw-aways all the time.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- Perl:

  ```
  perl -ne 'for$i(0..3){print}' file
  ```

  and I have to add this one posted as a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81904/probably-simple-sed-perl-awk-question/81905?noredirect=1#comment120991_81905) by @derobert because it is just cool:

  ```
  perl -ne 'print "$_" x4'
  ```
- `awk` and variants:

  ```
  awk '{for(i=0;i<4;i++)print}' file
  ```
- `bash`

  ```
  while read line; do for i in {1..4}; do echo "$line"; done; done < file
  ```

Comment: `awk`'s `for` not needs braces if there is only one command to repeat. And `perl` is simpler if you use `foreach` loop: `for$i(0..3){print}`.

Comment: Alternative perl: `perl -ne 'print(($_)x4)'`. Also, you should quote `$line` (in echo) in your bash version.

Comment: In my case I needed Windows line-endings. [as seen here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-20) can achieve with `BEGIN { 
 ORS="\r\n"
}`

Answer (score 41):

I wonder if this is turning into a [golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) match:

```
sed 'p;p;p' 
awk '1;1;1;1' 
perl -lpE 'say;say;say'   # if Paul McCartney and Michael Jackson were hackers...
```

Explanation:

sed's `p` command is to print the current line. The default behaviour is to print the current line just before moving to the next line (that's why sed has `-n` to allow you to turn it off). Some older seds don't have the semicolon (I think) so it's possible you might have to do `sed -e p -e p -e p`

Awk works with `condition {action}` pairs. If the action is omitted, the default is to print the current line if the condition returns true. Awk, like many C-like languages, treats `1` as true. (For completeness, if the condition is omitted, the action will be executed for each record.)

Many perl functions take advantage of the "default" variable. This one-liner is equivalent to (on perl 5.16):

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -lpE 'say;say;say'
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
use feature 'current_sub', 'evalbytes', 'fc', 'say', 'state', 'switch', 'unicode_strings', 'unicode_eval';
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    say $_;
    say $_;
    say $_;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

Comment: +1, if it is, you're winning :) What exactly does the `1` do in awk? Shorthand for `print $0`?

Comment: Awk statements are made up of a condition and a block, either are optional, but one must be present.  The default condition is `1` (true); the default block is equivalent to `{print}`.  So the statement `1` would mean to print the current line buffer (`{print}`).  (`{print}` and `{print $0}` are mostly the same, qed.)

Comment: I've never heard of a `sed` that doesn't support semicolons as command terminators; is there really such a thing?

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -n '{p;p;p;p;}' file

awk '{print;print;print;print;}' file
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without requiring `sed`, `perl`, or `awk`.

```
$ for i in `cat <file>` ; do seq <#> <#> | xargs -i -- echo $i ; done
```

or using a while loop:

```
$ while read i ; do seq <#> <#> | xargs -i -- echo $i ; done < <file>
```

#### Examples

*for loop*

```
$ for i in `cat sample.txt` ; do seq 1 3 | xargs -i -- echo $i ; done
a
a
a
b
b
b
c
c
c
```

*while loop*

```
$ while read i; do seq 1 2| xargs -i -- echo $i;done < sample.txt
a
a
b
b
c
c
```

Comment: I think the for loop version will break on any lines containing whitespace, so the while loop should be preferred. Otherwise, +1 since I'm a sucker for shell solutions.

Comment: @evilsoup - yes someone else mentioned this as well on some code I posted on another Q&A. I think that's the primary advantage of while over for, the while loop is tolerant of the $IFS separator and will split on end-of-line whereas the for splits on $IFS.

Answer (score 2):

Using purely shell:

```
repeats=4
while read line; do yes $line|head --lines=$repeats; done < infile > outfile
```

Comment: Does somebody know how to make yes consider `--help` as a string instead of an option? [consider the case where `line` is `--help` or another option]

Comment: yes, `yes -- --help`

Comment: Using `yes` and `head` means this is not "purely shell"

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'h;:a;s/[^\n]\+/&/4;t;G;ba' file
```

Will repeat each line 4 times.

Or if you prefer:

```
sed 'h;:a;s/\n/&/3;t;G;ba' file
```

Where you repeat each line 3 more times.

Answer (score 2):

@potong 's answer does not work with empty lines, replacing `\+` with `*` should fix it:

```bsh
sed 'h;:a;s/[^\n]*/&/4;t;G;ba' file
```